# Twitter does not load images anywhere

Tags: images, twitter

I recently noticed that my Twitter app on Android does not load any new images. The ones stored in the cache still continue to open, but none new are downloaded. I cleared the app data, uninstalled updates (it is a pre-installed app), and restarted my phone, all being some of the solutions I found over the internet, but none worked. But it turns out the problem goes deeper than that.

I installed a couple other Twitter clients for Android, and they both fail to load the images too. I opened Twitter on my laptop, and no images there as well. Does anybody know why this could be and how to solve this?

P.S. I'm not sure if this question qualifies for this Stack site, but since I couldn't find any other site that was remotely relevant to my question, I went ahead with this. Also, not that I think it matters now but just in case, my phone is a One M8 with Lollipop installed.

Comment: are you using any adblocker type apps on your device?

Comment: None on my phone. Though desktop browser does have one. But don't think that's the reason, because the photos used to show up even when I had it. The problem mysteriously went away a day after posting this question, but it's back now just as suddenly. Can't figure it out whatsoever.